# http get on dart take long time to return status of the response

Tags: http, flutter, dart

i'm using this Method to check if the app can access to the target url

```
Future<bool> ip() async {
var url = 'http://192.168.2.176/applications.html';try {
http.Response response = await http.get((url));return true;} catch (_) {print('WTF');
return false;}}
```

my problem is , when the function will return false if the response failed 
then it will need about 30 seconds to give me the boolean result as false value. 
is there any way to solve this issue , 
i need the function to return false in 5 seconds if the url not accessible.

Comment: Use the lower level http client and set its connect timeout. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-io/HttpClient/connectionTimeout.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your help . i will use it now , many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just check out this code may be it might help you out :

```
try {
  final request = await client.get(...);
  final response = await request.close()
    .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  // rest of the code
  ...
} on TimeoutException catch (_) {
  // A timeout occurred.
} on SocketException catch (_) {
  // Other exception
}
```

modify you code accordingly let me know if it works.